# Java invariant exception

Tags: java, exception, error-handling, invariants

I have a project in which certain data has invariants which are not enforceable using language constructs, but I've intended to write my code such that they are maintained. If they are for some reason broken, it means that my code is buggy. I have some sanity check code which can discover if these invariants have been broken, but I'm not sure what is the canonical Java approach to responding to such a condition - is there some standard exception that I should throw? Use an assert?

Note that this is an issue of a value being set incorrectly at some point. The error itself does not occur at the time of the sanity check, but rather it occurred in the past, and the sanity check is just now discovering it (ie, it's not bad that the sanity check itself is running, it's just bad that the check failed).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Throw an [`IllegalStateException`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/IllegalStateException.html). It is meant specifically for purposes like this.

Comment: I'm finding many different implementations from various companies - can you provide a link? Thanks.

Comment: I'm not sure the definition of `IllegalStateException` fits very well with the invariant issue: `method has been invoked at an illegal or inappropriate time`.

Answer (score 1):

Deciding how your application would react to a broken invariant would be a sensible first step

In case a broken invariant is unrecoverable and basically means a bug a code, i second an answer about [IllegalStateException.html](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/IllegalStateException.html) (you may want to add some useful context for debug purposes ,e.g. variables in broken invariant) - such unchecked exception would stop a running thread

In case you can recover from broken invariant (by replacing some arguments with sensible default, giving it a second try) - you may want to throw a checked exception and catch it on one of upper layers and execute plan B

Comment: Hey, I just clarified my question a bit in response to your answer (which, given what I'd written before, was totally reasonable, and still is). According to the documentation: "Signals that a method has been invoked at an illegal or inappropriate time." This isn't quite the right thing, since it's not that this variable shouldn't have this value right /now/, but rather that it should /never/ have that value. Still, it's really close. It's almost the right thing, just not quite.

Comment: Ok.Why won't you try the following : Split the computation in a sequence of logical methods.Each method would use the data from previous steps, but perform checks on it first and throw IllegalArgumentException if check fails.Constructors for the initial set of values should do the same to check that they got right input parameters.This way you'll have ensure that on each step you'll have correct inputs

Comment: In this particular context, that wouldn't work, but I like the idea in theory. In any case, I think I'm going to go with IllegalStateException because it's the closest that I've found.